# How to sanity check a date in Java

Tags: java, validation, calendar, date

I find it curious that the most obvious way to create `Date` objects in Java has been deprecated and appears to have been "substituted" with a not so obvious to use lenient calendar.

How do you check that a date, given as a combination of day, month, and year, is a valid date?

For instance, 2008-02-31 (as in yyyy-mm-dd) would be an invalid date.

Comment: For anyone with a similar question, please consider whether you need non-Gregorian calendar support.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The current way is to use the calendar class.  It has the [setLenient](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) method that will validate the date and throw and exception if it is out of range as in your example.

Forgot to add:
If you get a calendar instance and set the time using your date, this is how you get the validation.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setLenient(false);
cal.setTime(yourDate);
try {
    cal.getTime();
}
catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Invalid date");
}
```

Comment: don't think this exactly works as-is. Calendar.setTime takes java.util.Date, so the conversion from string has already happened by the time you get a "yourDate" object.

Comment: 3 problems with the example code:
1. After getting a Calendar instance, you must call cal.setLenient(false). Otherwise a date like Feb 31 2007 will be considered valid.
2. An exception doesn't get thrown by cal.setTime(). You must call cal.getTime() after the setTime() call, which throws an exception on invalid date.
3. Typo: Missing a '}' before the catch.

Comment: This is also slower than other approaches. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149680/regex-date-format-validation-on-java/18252071#18252071

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: doesn't validate dates like 31 Feb

Answer (score 91):

Key is `df.setLenient(false);`. This is more than enough for simple cases. If you are looking for a more robust (I doubt that) and/or alternate libraries like [joda-time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/), then look at the [answer by user "tardate"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/892204/1076848)

```
final static String DATE_FORMAT = "dd-MM-yyyy";

public static boolean isDateValid(String date)
{
        try {
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
            df.setLenient(false);
            df.parse(date);
            return true;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Try with "09-04-201a". It will create a crazy date.

Comment: @ceklock that's the way it works, no matter if you use `setLenient` or not: `SimpleDateFormat` will always parse until the pattern is matched and ignore the rest of the string, thus you get `201` as year.

Comment: @ceklock I just addressed it in [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30528952/1276636). It may save a minute or two for someone.

Comment: Incorporating exception handling entails a big performance hit, so this is probably a bad design IF you expect malformed input in normal operation (e.g. validating user input). But if the method is used as a double-check against inputs that are supposed to be valid all the time (except for bugs), it is fine.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 49):

As shown by @Maglob, the basic approach is to test the conversion from string to date using [SimpleDateFormat.parse](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). That will catch invalid day/month combinations like 2008-02-31.

However, in practice that is rarely enough since SimpleDateFormat.parse is exceedingly liberal. There are two behaviours you might be concerned with:

**Invalid characters in the date string**
Surprisingly, 2008-02-2x will "pass" as a valid date with locale format = "yyyy-MM-dd" for example. Even when isLenient==false.

**Years: 2, 3 or 4 digits?**
You may also want to enforce 4-digit years rather than allowing the default SimpleDateFormat behaviour (which will interpret "12-02-31" differently depending on whether your format was "yyyy-MM-dd" or "yy-MM-dd")

### A Strict Solution with the Standard Library

So a complete string to date test could look like this: a combination of regex match, and then a forced date conversion. The trick with the regex is to make it locale-friendly.

```
  Date parseDate(String maybeDate, String format, boolean lenient) {
    Date date = null;

    // test date string matches format structure using regex
    // - weed out illegal characters and enforce 4-digit year
    // - create the regex based on the local format string
    String reFormat = Pattern.compile("d+|M+").matcher(Matcher.quoteReplacement(format)).replaceAll("\\\\d{1,2}");
    reFormat = Pattern.compile("y+").matcher(reFormat).replaceAll("\\\\d{4}");
    if ( Pattern.compile(reFormat).matcher(maybeDate).matches() ) {

      // date string matches format structure, 
      // - now test it can be converted to a valid date
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = (SimpleDateFormat)DateFormat.getDateInstance();
      sdf.applyPattern(format);
      sdf.setLenient(lenient);
      try { date = sdf.parse(maybeDate); } catch (ParseException e) { }
    } 
    return date;
  } 

  // used like this:
  Date date = parseDate( "21/5/2009", "d/M/yyyy", false);
```

Note that the regex assumes the format string contains only day, month, year, and separator characters. Aside from that, format can be in any locale format: "d/MM/yy", "yyyy-MM-dd", and so on. The format string for the current locale could be obtained like this:

```
Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = (SimpleDateFormat)DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locale );
String format = sdf.toPattern();
```

### Joda Time - Better Alternative?

I've been hearing about [joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) recently and thought I'd compare. Two points:

1. Seems better at being strict about invalid characters in the date string, unlike SimpleDateFormat
2. Can't see a way to enforce 4-digit years with it yet (but I guess you could create your own [DateTimeFormatter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for this purpose)

It's quite simple to use:

```
import org.joda.time.format.*;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

org.joda.time.DateTime parseDate(String maybeDate, String format) {
  org.joda.time.DateTime date = null;
  try {
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format);
    date =  fmt.parseDateTime(maybeDate);
  } catch (Exception e) { }
  return date;
}
```

Comment: I ended up with the joda alternative and checking that the value matches the pattern length myself...

Comment: Update: The terrible old legacy classes (`Date`, `SimpleDateFormat`, etc.) are now supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes. Likewise, the *Joda-Time* project is in maintenance mode, and advises migration to the *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 42):

## tl;dr

Use the [strict mode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#STRICT) on [`java.time.DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to parse a [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html). Trap for the [`DateTimeParseException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html).

```
LocalDate.parse(                   // Represent a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.
    "31/02/2000" ,                 // Input string.
    DateTimeFormatter              // Define a formatting pattern to match your input string.
    .ofPattern ( "dd/MM/uuuu" )
    .withResolverStyle ( ResolverStyle.STRICT )  // Specify leniency in tolerating questionable inputs.
)
```

After parsing, you might check for reasonable value. For example, a birth date within last one hundred years.

```
birthDate.isAfter( LocalDate.now().minusYears( 100 ) )
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Avoid using the troublesome old date-time classes shipped with the earliest versions of Java. Now supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

## `LocalDate` & `DateTimeFormatter` & `ResolverStyle`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
String input = "31/02/2000";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "dd/MM/uuuu" );
try {
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse ( input , f );
    System.out.println ( "ld: " + ld );
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    System.out.println ( "ERROR: " + e );
}
```

The [`java.time.DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class can be set to parse strings with any of three leniency modes defined in the [`ResolverStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html) enum. We insert a line into the above code to try each of the modes.

```
f = f.withResolverStyle ( ResolverStyle.LENIENT );
```

The results:

- `ResolverStyle.LENIENT`
  ld: 2000-03-02
- `ResolverStyle.SMART`
  ld: 2000-02-29
- `ResolverStyle.STRICT`
  ERROR: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '31/02/2000' could not be parsed: Invalid date 'FEBRUARY 31'

We can see that in [`ResolverStyle.LENIENT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#LENIENT) mode, the invalid date is moved forward an equivalent number of days. In [`ResolverStyle.SMART`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#SMART) mode (the default), a logical decision is made to keep the date within the month and going with the last possible day of the month, Feb 29 in a leap year, as there is no 31st day in that month. The [`ResolverStyle.STRICT`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#STRICT) mode throws an exception complaining that there is no such date.

All three of these are reasonable depending on your business problem and policies. Sounds like in your case you want the strict mode to reject the invalid date rather than adjust it.

---

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy.]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Well, assume that the project is being compiled with java 8+, then your answer is correct. I'm using these classes too when the project is in java 8. But sometimes I have to touch those ugly ancient jsp scriptlets (that even doesn't support java 7). Validating dates there is a pain. Hence I'm here. Yet your answer is the most correct approach... Conclusion: I am screwed.

Comment: @KarelG Re-read that second-to-last paragraph about [back-port to Java 6 & Java 7](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). I have not verified this behavior in the back-port but I suggest you give it a try.

Answer (score 40):

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

For example something like:

```
boolean isLegalDate(String s) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    sdf.setLenient(false);
    return sdf.parse(s, new ParsePosition(0)) != null;
}
```

Comment: One of the issues with this approach is that its gonna accept 0003-0002-001.

Comment: Another issue is that setting 13 in the month returns a Date where the month is 01 the following year.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 16):

## java.time

With the [Date and Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) ([java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes) built into Java 8 and later, you can use the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class.

```
public static boolean isDateValid(int year, int month, int day) {
    try {
        LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
    } catch (DateTimeException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: By default, this code uses `ResolverStyle.SMART` which adjusts the resulting value to a valid date rather than throwing an exception. So this code will not accomplish the goal of the Question. See [my Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39649815/642706) for example and for solution using `ResolverStyle.STRICT`.

Comment: @BasilBourqueno no it doesn't. Just tested and `LocalDate.of()` works just like `DateTimeFormatter` with `.withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)`.

Answer (score 8):

Building on [Aravind's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226910/how-to-sanity-check-a-date-in-java/4528094#4528094) to fix the problem pointed out by [ceklock in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226910/how-to-sanity-check-a-date-in-java/30528952#comment35086192_4528094), I added a method to verify that the `dateString` doesn't contain any invalid character.

Here is how I do:

```
private boolean isDateCorrect(String dateString) {
    try {
        Date date = mDateFormatter.parse(dateString);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        return matchesOurDatePattern(dateString);    //added my method
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * This will check if the provided string matches our date format
 * @param dateString
 * @return true if the passed string matches format 2014-1-15 (YYYY-MM-dd)
 */
private boolean matchesDatePattern(String dateString) {
    return dateString.matches("^\\d+\\-\\d+\\-\\d+");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

An alternative strict solution using the standard library is to perform the following:

1) Create a strict SimpleDateFormat using your pattern

2) Attempt to parse the user entered value using the format object

3) If successful, reformat the Date resulting from (2) using the same date format (from (1))

4) Compare the reformatted date against the original, user-entered value. If they're equal then the value entered strictly matches your pattern.

This way, you don't need to create complex regular expressions - in my case I needed to support all of SimpleDateFormat's pattern syntax, rather than be limited to certain types like just days, months and years.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go, see also sample code on http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/14886-date-validation-using-simpledateformat/

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to use `org.apache.commons.validator.GenericValidator` class from apache.

`GenericValidator.isDate(String value, String datePattern, boolean strict);`

Note: strict - Whether or not to have an exact match of the datePattern.

Comment: I have added the answer with the method of GenericValidator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68069005/2024527

Answer (score 5):

I think the simpliest is just to convert a string into a date object and convert it back to a string. The given date string is fine if both strings still match.

```
public boolean isDateValid(String dateString, String pattern)
{   
    try
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
        if (sdf.format(sdf.parse(dateString)).equals(dateString))
            return true;
    }
    catch (ParseException pe) {}

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that both of those are Strings (otherwise they'd already be valid Dates), here's one way:

```
package cruft;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateValidator
{
    private static final DateFormat DEFAULT_FORMATTER;

    static
    {
        DEFAULT_FORMATTER = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        DEFAULT_FORMATTER.setLenient(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for (String dateString : args)
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("arg: " + dateString + " date: " + convertDateString(dateString));
            }
            catch (ParseException e)
            {
                System.out.println("could not parse " + dateString);
            }
        }
    }

    public static Date convertDateString(String dateString) throws ParseException
    {
        return DEFAULT_FORMATTER.parse(dateString);
    }
}
```

Here's the output I get:

```
java cruft.DateValidator 32-11-2010 31-02-2010 04-01-2011
could not parse 32-11-2010
could not parse 31-02-2010
arg: 04-01-2011 date: Tue Jan 04 00:00:00 EST 2011

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see, it does handle both of your cases nicely.

Comment: @duffymo the second statement isn't throwing exception... :(

Comment: @Pangea Not really.... try this date "31-01-2010" it won't throw any exception..........Just run it on your machine and see... it doesn't work....

Comment: My bad. I removed my comment. But the second statement is throwing exception for me though. @duffymo - which jvm are you using?

Comment: @Pangea i am using jdk1.6.0_23 I tried this with this even http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/ but even that didn't work....

Comment: What did not work? Try doing a sys out of date 2 and post what is being printed here. I tried it with 1.6.0_20-b02.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "31-02-2010"
 at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:337)

Comment: @maximus: that's because the first has thrown an exception and thus the remnant of the code won't be executed. @sasidhar: that's because 31 january is a valid date. @duffymo: consider putting each in a try-catch so that both get executed ;)

Comment: I understand this is just a simple test but to just to make sure that people doesn't copy this verbatim, I want to say "DateFormat" IS NOT THREAD SAFE. So always create it as a local variable or use it with thread local.

Comment: @Pangea just figured out that the 31st of February doesn't throw an exception if we use the date format as "dd-mm-yyyy" it has to be "dd-MM-yyyy" that was the little thing worrying me from days, just noticed that i was using small letter for month, any way thanks. Any idea what the small m's mean ?

Comment: small m is used to indicate minutes. seems like SimpleDateFormat is more forgiving that desired ;-). Look here for the supported symbols and their interpretations: http://mboshart.dyndns.org/boshart/documentation/APIdocs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#month

Answer (score 2):

This is working great for me. Approach suggested above by Ben.

```
private static boolean isDateValid(String s) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    try {
        Date d = asDate(s);
        if (sdf.format(d).equals(s)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: can't recognize asDate. What is that?

Answer (score 2):

looks like ***SimpleDateFormat*** is not checking the pattern strictly even after *setLenient(false);* method is applied on it, so i have used below method to validate if the date inputted is valid date or not as per supplied pattern.

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
public boolean isValidFormat(String dateString, String pattern) {
    boolean valid = true;
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
    try {
        formatter.parse(dateString);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two comments on the use of SimpleDateFormat.

> it should be declared as a static instance
>   if declared as static access should be synchronized as it is not thread safe

IME that is better that instantiating an instance for each parse of a date.

Comment: good point Tom. I updated the example I provided to make sure consistently using static instance.

Comment: Using a synchronized function might not scale for some projects. I would recommand putting the SimpleDateFormat in a ThreadLocal variable instead of a static variable accessed through a synchronized function.

Answer (score 0):

Above methods of date parsing are nice , i just added new check in existing methods that double check the converted date  with original date using formater, so it works for almost each case as i verified. e.g. 02/29/2013 is invalid date.
Given function parse the date according to current acceptable date formats. It returns true if date is not parsed successfully.

```
 public final boolean validateDateFormat(final String date) {
        String[] formatStrings = {"MM/dd/yyyy"};
        boolean isInvalidFormat = false;
        Date dateObj;
        for (String formatString : formatStrings) {
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = (SimpleDateFormat) DateFormat.getDateInstance();
                sdf.applyPattern(formatString);
                sdf.setLenient(false);
                dateObj = sdf.parse(date);
                System.out.println(dateObj);
                if (date.equals(sdf.format(dateObj))) {
                    isInvalidFormat = false;
                    break;
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                isInvalidFormat = true;
            }
        }
        return isInvalidFormat;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did for Node environment using no external libraries:

```
Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
   var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
   var mm = (this.getMonth()+1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
   var dd  = this.getDate().toString();
   return zeroPad([yyyy, mm, dd].join('-'));  
};

function zeroPad(date_string) {
   var dt = date_string.split('-');
   return dt[0] + '-' + (dt[1][1]?dt[1]:"0"+dt[1][0]) + '-' + (dt[2][1]?dt[2]:"0"+dt[2][0]);
}

function isDateCorrect(in_string) {
   if (!matchesDatePattern) return false;
   in_string = zeroPad(in_string);
   try {
      var idate = new Date(in_string);
      var out_string = idate.yyyymmdd();
      return in_string == out_string;
   } catch(err) {
      return false;
   }

   function matchesDatePattern(date_string) {
      var dateFormat = /[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+/;
      return dateFormat.test(date_string); 
   }
}
```

And here is how to use it:

```
isDateCorrect('2014-02-23')
true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// to return valid days of month, according to month and year
int returnDaysofMonth(int month, int year) {
    int daysInMonth;
    boolean leapYear;
    leapYear = checkLeap(year);
    if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
        daysInMonth = 30;
    else if (month == 2)
        daysInMonth = (leapYear) ? 29 : 28;
    else
        daysInMonth = 31;
    return daysInMonth;
}

// to check a year is leap or not
private boolean checkLeap(int year) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    return cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) > 365;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is I would check the date format:

```
 public static boolean checkFormat(String dateTimeString) {
    return dateTimeString.matches("^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}") || dateTimeString.matches("^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}")
            || dateTimeString.matches("^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}") || dateTimeString
            .matches("^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}Z") ||
            dateTimeString.matches("^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}Z");
}
```

Comment: We have the modern [*java.time* classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) for this work now. Writing complicated regex is not likely the best use of your time. See the one-liner in [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39649815/642706).

Answer (score 0):

```
        public static String detectDateFormat(String inputDate, String requiredFormat) {
        String tempDate = inputDate.replace("/", "").replace("-", "").replace(" ", "");
        String dateFormat;

        if (tempDate.matches("([0-12]{2})([0-31]{2})([0-9]{4})")) {
            dateFormat = "MMddyyyy";
        } else if (tempDate.matches("([0-31]{2})([0-12]{2})([0-9]{4})")) {
            dateFormat = "ddMMyyyy";
        } else if (tempDate.matches("([0-9]{4})([0-12]{2})([0-31]{2})")) {
            dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd";
        } else if (tempDate.matches("([0-9]{4})([0-31]{2})([0-12]{2})")) {
            dateFormat = "yyyyddMM";
        } else if (tempDate.matches("([0-31]{2})([a-z]{3})([0-9]{4})")) {
            dateFormat = "ddMMMyyyy";
        } else if (tempDate.matches("([a-z]{3})([0-31]{2})([0-9]{4})")) {
            dateFormat = "MMMddyyyy";
        } else if (tempDate.matches("([0-9]{4})([a-z]{3})([0-31]{2})")) {
            dateFormat = "yyyyMMMdd";
        } else if (tempDate.matches("([0-9]{4})([0-31]{2})([a-z]{3})")) {
            dateFormat = "yyyyddMMM";
        } else {
            return "Pattern Not Added";
//add your required regex
        }
        try {
            String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat(requiredFormat, Locale.ENGLISH).format(new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat).parse(tempDate));

            return formattedDate;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //
            return "";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

setLenient to false if you like a strict validation

```
public boolean isThisDateValid(String dateToValidate, String dateFromat){

    if(dateToValidate == null){
        return false;
    }

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFromat);
    sdf.setLenient(false);

    try {

        //if not valid, it will throw ParseException
        Date date = sdf.parse(dateToValidate);
        System.out.println(date);

    } catch (ParseException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With 'legacy' date format, we can format the result and compare it back to the source.

```
    public boolean isValidFormat(String source, String pattern) {
    SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    sd.setLenient(false);
    try {
        Date date = sd.parse(source);
        return date != null && sd.format(date).equals(source);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This execerpt says 'false' to source=01.01.04 with pattern '01.01.2004'

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `org.apache.commons.validator.GenericValidator`'s method directly without adding the whole library:

```
public static boolean isValidDate(String value, String datePattern, boolean strict) {

    if (value == null
            || datePattern == null
            || datePattern.length() <= 0) {

        return false;
    }

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern, Locale.ENGLISH);
    formatter.setLenient(false);

    try {
        formatter.parse(value);
    } catch(ParseException e) {
        return false;
    }

    if (strict && (datePattern.length() != value.length())) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I recommend not. The `SimpleDateFormat` class used in that Apache code is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Also the length check is not sound (though you can probably find corner cases where it gives the expected result).

Comment: `isValidDate("August 14, 2021", "MMMM d, yyyy", true)`, which I believe to be 100 % valid, yields `false`. And `isValidDate("May 9, 2021?", "MMMM d, yyyy", true)`, with the question mark that should not be allowed there, yields `true`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and elegant way for **Android developers**  (Java 8 not required):

```
// month value is 1-based. e.g., 1 for January.
public static boolean isDateValid(int year, int month, int day) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    try {
        calendar.setLenient(false);
        calendar.set(year, month-1, day);
        calendar.getTime();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works with dd/MM/yyyy format and can be used to check NotNull,NotEmpty as well.

public static boolean validateJavaDate(String strDate) {

```
    if (strDate != null && !strDate.isEmpty() && !strDate.equalsIgnoreCase(" ")) {
        {

            SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            date.setLenient(false);

            try {
                Date javaDate = date.parse(strDate);
                System.out.println(strDate + " Valid Date format");
            }

            catch (ParseException e) {
                System.out.println(strDate + " Invalid Date format");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

    } else {
        System.out.println(strDate + "----> Date is Null/Empty");
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for wanting to contribute. Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Also are you contributing anything new? The checking for null and empty is already in the answer by SANAT.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way without using any external library would be:

```
private static final Pattern p_DATE = Pattern.compile("^\\s*(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)\\s*$");

private static Date parseDate(String v) {
    
    if ( v==null || v.isBlank() ) {
        return null;
    }
    
    // 2023-03-02
    Matcher m = p_DATE.matcher(v);
    
    if ( ! m.find() ) {
        return null;
    }
    
    int day = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3), 10);
    int mon = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2), 10);
    int year = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1), 10);
    
    // convert years prior to 99
    if ( year<99 ) {
        year += 2000;
    }
    
    if ( 
            (day<0 || day>31) ||
            (mon<1 || mon>12) 
    ) {
        return null;
    }
    
    // validate max day
    int maxDayOfTheMonth = getMaxDayOfTheMonth(mon, year);

    if ( day > maxDayOfTheMonth ) {
        return null;
    }
    
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, mon-1);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    
    return cal.getTime();
}

private static int getMaxDayOfTheMonth(int mon, int year) {
    
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, mon-1);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
    
    return cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
}
```

Comment: Strongly discouraged. The `Calendar` class was cumbersome to work with and for that reason was supplanted by java.time, the modern Java date and time API, nearly 10 years ago. Use java.time and your task will be an immense lot easier and simpler. It’s built-in since Java 8. Also no one should wnat an old-fashioned `Date` since that Java version. I agree not to use any external library.

Comment: Compare your 60 lines, some of which I don’t understand readily, with the 6 lines solution in [the good answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39649815/5772882). How can you call your way simple? I can’t make any sense of that claim.