# How to Use this type of string data in Android?

Tags: java, android, regex, json

I am working with a web service for my next android application. This web service returns me some data, which is in an escape sequence and in JSON format. I am not able to process it using Java in Android.

The problem that I'm having with the data is for the following string example:

`http:\\/\\/www.example.com\\/temp\\/`.

Apparently Java can not let me have an escape sequence that contains `\/` in it. 
It would not even let me put that in a double quote, so that I could use an unescape utility. Can you please help me with it?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Try this..

> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575116/forward-slash-in-java-regex
> 
> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111985/java-forward-slash-escape-character

Comment: I'm sorry. The string in the question was posted wrong. HTML removed that escape sequence. Please read my question now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is that you are escaping a forward slash ( / ). JAVA does not need forward slash to be escaped.

instead of an url string like below

```
http:\/\/www.example.com\/temp\/
```

set the url string as below

```
http://www.example.com/temp/
```