# How to escape forward slash in java so that to use it in path

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to escape forward slash in String which can be used in path using Java.
For example: `String:: "Test/World"`
Now I want to use above string path.At the same time I have to make sure that `"Test/World"` will come as it is in path. Sorry if its duplicate but I couldn't find any satisfactory solution for this.
My purpose is to use above string to create nodes in Zookeeper.
*Example:*
If I use following string to create node in Zokkeeper then I should get "Test/World" as a single node not separate. Zookeeper accepts "/" as path separator which in some cases I dont require.
`/zookeeper/HellowWorld/Test/World`

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - Forward Slash Escape Character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111985/java-forward-slash-escape-character)

Comment: Hi Sushain. I am not sure how it is duplicate.

Answer (score 15):

You should know about `File.separator` ... This is safer than `\` or `/` because Linux and Windows use different file separators. Using `File.separator` will make your program run regardless of the platform it is being run on, after all, that is the point of the JVM. -- forward slash will work, however, `File.separator` will make you end users more confident that it will.

And you [don't need to escape](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) `"/` ... you should [also see the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2417546/3100494)

```
String fileP = "Test" + File.separator + "World";
```

Comment: Using File.Separator also Zookeeper created Test and World as two separate entities(As part of Path). What I am trying to find is how to escape it so that I will get node as "Test/World"

Comment: Have you tried that? I believe File.Separator will return the string for you... Are you trying to iterate through the elements of the path and concatenate to a single string?

Comment: Yes I have to form it as single String other wise it will not be accepted as path in Zookeeper. Yes I tried your approach.

Comment: check the second example here, see if getResource() can help you http://www.qualitybrain.com/?p=3

Answer (score 5):

In order to escape a character in Java use "\"
for example:

```
String strPath = "directory\\file.txt".
```

I believe you do not need to escape forward slashes such as: "/"

Comment: Your belief is correct. It would be nice to include a [source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) though. :)

Comment: Yes I need to use this path in Zookeeper as well as normal file system.

Answer (score 2):

Let me rephrase your question. You are trying to create a node in zookeeper and it should be /zookeeper/HelloWorld/NodeName. But the last part "NodeName" is actually "Test/World", and you are looking for ways to escape "/" so the node name can be "Test/World".

I don't think it would work escaping the char, unless you tried with unicode.

Try \u002F which is the equivalent for /.

Comment: I tries but at zookeeper level it takes it as "/" and forms separate node.

Comment: Is there a way to rename nodes once created? Maybe the / could work for renaming a node.

Comment: This sorted my situation. I wanted to write "n/a" and ended up with "\"n\u002Fa\"". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We are trying to solve exactly the same problem (using filesystem path as node name in zookeeper) a we haven't found a way how to have '/' in node name.

Solution would be either to replace '/' with some character, that cannot appear in your node name. For paths that would be '/' or '\0', which wont help us in this case.

Other possibility is to replace '/' with string of characters allowed in node name, e.g. "Test/World" -> "Test%@World", "Test%World" -> "Test%%World" and add escaping/de-escaping to saving and loading.

If there is any more straightforward way, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Zookeeper.  But it looks to me as though you're trying to keep a list of strings like `"zookeeper", "HellowWorld", "Test/World"`, that you then want to use either to create Zookeeper nodes *or* to create a pathname in a file system.  (I'm assuming that if you're working with a file system, you're going to have a subdirectory `Test` and a file or subdirectory `World` in the `Test` subdirectory.  If you're actually trying to create a single file or directory named `Test/World`, give up.  Both Linux and Windows will fight with you.)

If that's the case, then don't try to represent the "path" as a simple `String` that you pass around in your program.  Instead, represent it as a `String[]` or `ArrayList<String>`, and then convert it to a filesystem path name only when you need a filesystem path name.  Or, better, define your own class with a `getFilesystemPath` method.  Converting your list of node names to a pathname `String` too early, and then trying to reconstruct the list from the `String` later, is a poor approach because you throw away data that you need later (in particular, you're throwing away information about which `/` characters are separators and which ones are part of node names).

**EDIT:** If you also need a single path name for Zookeeper, as you mentioned in another comment, I can't help you since I don't know Zookeeper and haven't found anything in a quick look at the docs.  If there is a way to escape the slash for Zookeeper, then I still recommend defining your own class, with a `getFilesystemPath` method and a `getZookeeperPath` method, since the two methods will probably return different `String`s in certain cases.  The class would internally keep the names as an array or `ArrayList`.