# How can i parse json object containing slashes in java

Tags: java, json, gson

I want to parse a windows path in java.
this is part of the json:

`..."sslkey":"c:\usr\ssl\key.jks"`

and this is the code:

```
JsonObject jsonargs = gson.fromJson(args[0], JsonObject.class);
SSLKEY = jsonargs.get("sslkey").getAsString();
```

I tried with `\` also in the value, but the error that I have is:

> Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>   com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at
>   line 1 column 133 path $.sslkey

Could you please tell me how I can fix this?

Thank you !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape forward slash in java so that to use it in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643025/how-to-escape-forward-slash-in-java-so-that-to-use-it-in-path)

Comment: `{"sslkey": "c:\usr\ssl\key.jks"}` - is not a valid `JSON`. You can `replace` "\" char with `/` and try to deserialise after.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, i tried many things , it seems that : is also special char. I used base64 encode in php and base64 decode in java.. so all fine :)