# JMeter Beanshell Postprocessor : Reading a file

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner, beanshell

I am using the below script in a Beanshell Postprocessor

```
import java.io.*;
File f =new File ("C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\testresults.csv");
FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(f,true);
BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(fw);

var r=prev.getResponseCode();

if (r.equals("200"))

{
    bw.write("Test Passed");
    }

    else
    {
        bw.write("Test failed");
        }
bw.close();
fw.close();
```

But I am getting the below error
BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.*; File f =new File ("C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\testresults.csv") . . . '' Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 2, column 23.  Encountered: "U" (85), after : ""C:\".

What could cause the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [escape a backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643025/how-to-escape-forward-slash-in-java-so-that-to-use-it-in-path) with a backslash like:

```
C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\Desktop\\testresults.csv
```

or use a forward slash instead:

```
C:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/testresults.csv
```

A couple more hints:

1. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting
2. If you run your test with 2 or more concurrent threads they will be writing into the same file resulting in data corruption due to a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) so maybe it worth considering switching to [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin) instead

Answer (score 0):

Change to JSR223 Post Processor and write as one line (groovy default)

```
new File("C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Desktop\\\testresults.csv") << (prev.getResponseCode().equals("200") ? "Test Passed" : "Test failed")
```