# Invalid Date Format Error in JAVA

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sanity check a date in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226910/how-to-sanity-check-a-date-in-java)

I want to convert a String into Date..with a condition that accepted String format should be only this `yyyy/MM/dd-HH:MM:SS`.

Date provided in any other format should give error.

```
try {
    String str_date = "25/09/2012-13:43:20";
    DateFormat formatter;
    Date date;
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd-hh:mm:ss");
    date = (Date) formatter.parse(str_date);
    System.out.println("Today is " + date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println("Exception :" + e);
}
```

Since `str_date` is having format `dd/MM/yyyy-hh:mm:ss`, which is invalid it should through exception, but it is not throwing any expection.

The output is `Today is Mon Mar 05 13:43:20 IST 31`

Comment: You might like to have a read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226910/how-to-sanity-check-a-date-in-java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just a quick look at the Java doc for the parse method you are using and it says this:

> By default, parsing is lenient: If the input is not in the form used by this object's format method but can still be parsed as a date, then the parse succeeds. Clients may insist on strict adherence to the format by calling setLenient(false).

Try putting `formatter.setLenient(false);` on the line after formatter is instantiated. That will force the formatter to use ONLY the format you have specified.

Comment: I tried it in the above way, but then also it is given exception even for the correct format.

Comment: try {  
  String str_date="2012/09/25-13:42:05";
  SimpleDateFormat formatter ; 
  Date date ; 
   formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd-hh:mm:ss");
   formatter.setLenient(false);
   date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date);  
  System.out.println("Today is " +date );
   } catch (ParseException e)
   {System.out.println("Exception :"+e);  }  
  
  }

Answer (score 2):

```
  formatter.setLenient(false);
```

shall provide you with desired exception

Froum javadocs:

By default, parsing is lenient: If the input is not in the form used
 by this object's format method but can still be parsed as a date, then
 the parse succeeds.  Clients may insist on strict adherence to the
 format by calling setLenient(false).

Answer (score 0):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29):

```
ParseException - if the *beginning* of the specified string cannot be parsed.
```

Try

```
String str_date="25:09/2012-13:43:20";
```

This will throw a ParseException.

Answer (score 0):

Your format should specify `HH` rather than `hh`.  Otherwise, 13 o'clock is time to get a new watch.