# check whether is date suit the define date pattern

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

User should enter date in the next format `yyyy-MM-dd`. So I check it on my side using:

```
public static boolean isDateValid(SimpleDateFormat dateFormat, String date) {
    try {
        dateFormat.parse(date);
        return true;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

But it returns true even I enter `12-12-2012` for the

```
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: why do you want to force the user doing this - shouln't it be enough for you to just check if its a valid date - no matter what format? --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226910/how-to-sanity-check-a-date-in-java  after oyu have validated you can you your simpledateformat to format the date the way you want it to be

Comment: @tenhouse : in this case, what date would 10-12-2012 be ? 10th of december or 12th of october ?

Comment: @njzk2 agreed. I didn't think of that

Comment: is this date string came from user input like EditText? ... if so ... you can use DatePicker or DatePickerDialog instead

Comment: @tenhouse : but the opposite is true as well : if this is user input, the user may type 2012-12-10 as wel as 10-12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`DateFormat.setLenient(false)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29), to avoid doing `lenient` parsing: -

```
    try {
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        dateFormat.parse(date);
        return true;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
```

From the docs: -

> With lenient parsing, the parser may use heuristics to interpret
>   inputs that do not precisely match this object's format. With strict
>   parsing, inputs must match this object's format.

Comment: in this case 12-12-12 is considered like valid data for "yyyy-MM-dd" date format.

Comment: Probably it is taken as `0012-12-12`. And if it is doing like that, probably it will also work for - `12-2-2`. Please try it.