# How to validate date(dd-mm-yyyy) without using regular expression in java?

Tags: java

I am wandering is there any way to validate date in format `dd-mm-yyyy` WITHOUT using any regular expression so that it has to accept date until today's date in java and validation includes checking leap year too ? Accepting input from user and validating in method ?

Comment: A regex isn't the right tool to validate a date anyway (do you want to write a regex  able to check if there was 29 days in February that year ?). Use a date parser.

Comment: How to use date parser ? please help.. I am new to this language

Comment: Look at the linked QA : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194290/validating-a-date-in-java