# Prevent invalid date from getting converted into date of next month in jdk6?

Tags: java, jdk6

Consider the snippet:

```
String dateStr = "Mon Jan 32 00:00:00 IST 2015";    // 32 Jan 2015

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
DateFormat ddMMyyyy = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
System.out.println(ddMMyyyy.format(formatter.parse(dateStr)));
```

gives me the output as

```
01.02.2015     //   Ist February 2015
```

I wish to prevent this to make the user aware on the UI that is an invalid date?
Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sanity check a date in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226910/how-to-sanity-check-a-date-in-java)

Comment: @Jens: The main problem is that how will I get dd.MM.yyyy format with Calendar class and then do the stuff with setLenient method.

Comment: Where possible avoid the java `Date` classes. Use http://www.joda.org/joda-time/ for Java 7 and older, and Java Time in Java 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option [`setLenient()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)) of your SimpleDateFormat is what you are looking for.

After you set isLenient to false, it will only accept correctly formatted dates anymore, and throw a ParseException in other cases.

```
String dateStr = "Mon Jan 32 00:00:00 IST 2015";    // 32 Jan 2015

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
formatter.setLenient(false);
DateFormat ddMMyyyy = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
try {
    System.out.println(ddMMyyyy.format(formatter.parse(dateStr)));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // Your date is invalid
}
```

Comment: Should that be `setLenient(false)` to be strict

Comment: @TimoSta: No, this didn't solved the problem. I am still getting the same answer.

Comment: @BrettWalker Correct, it should be false

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari Have a look at my edit. It should be set to false instead of true as Brett Walker pointed out.

Comment: @TimoSta:  Did you try with String dateStr = "Mon Jan 30 00:00:00 IST 2015";  In this case, it must not fail, but an unparseable exception is thrown.

Comment: @TimoSta: It's fine TimoSta. Jan 30 is not Monday. How can I be so stupid this evening?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DateFormat.setLenient(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) to (from the Javadoc) *with strict parsing, inputs must match this object's format.*

```
DateFormat ddMMyyyy = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
ddMMyyyy.setLenient(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the date formatter not to be lenient...

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
formatter.setLenient(false);
```