# Does GregorianCalendar constructor check invalid input?

Tags: java, validation, datetime

[GregorianCalendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar%28int,%20int,%20int%29) constructor have signature:

```
GregorianCalendar(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)
GregorianCalendar(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second)
```

What happen if I pass `month` or `dayOfMonth` out of constructor contract?

It is easy to check if month in 0-11 range. But it is impossible to check valid day (which should be  28/29/30/31?) without writing own Calendar implementation.

It should be nice if Java Platform checks user date input. I don't like to check if `2015-13-32` is valid ISO date in own code.

Comment: What happens?  Well, try it and find out.

Comment: Nothing happen, but that doesn't help. Because official docs say nothing on topic I ask question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor doesn't check, what you can do is to set the time after executing setLenient(false) which will make the Calendar to accept only valid values:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setLenient(false);
cal.set(2016, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 30);
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(cal.getTime()));
```

This example will throw an exception because 02/30/2016 is not a valid date (the exception is thrown by `cal.getTime()`).

Comment: I expect such answer )) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226910/how-to-sanity-check-a-date-in-java

Comment: To be clear what expression thrown exception? `cal.set()` or `cal.getTime()` or `SimpleDateFormat.format()`?

Comment: Good point, actually what throws the exception is `cal.getTime()`