# How can I check if my Date is correct?

Tags: java, date, format

I'm programming a window where the user has to type a date on a input field but I don't know how to check if the day or month are coherent or not (like day between 1-31 and month between 1-12)

```
    String string = "26/03/2017";
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy") ;

    try {
        Date date = format.parse(string);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is the piece of code where I'm formatting the Date, but I have no idea to check what I said before.

Comment: You can implement regex to validate date format

Comment: But what do you want exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to parse a string like this: `string = "36/03/2017";` can return a totally legal date object but an incorrect value respect the string.
for that case you can use the lenient flag of the class **SimpleDateFormat**, setting that flag to false will throw an exception for invalid strings representations of a date (e.g. 29 Feb 2017)

now, you can set the flag Lenient to false, and catch the exception

```
String string = "36/03/2017";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
format.setLenient(false);
try {
    Date date = format.parse(string);
    System.out.println(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

DateFormat has a property which named 'lenient' is default true.
You must set format.setLenient(false) to check validity of the date. if incorrect date is parsed, you get a ParseException.

Answer (score 0):

2017 answer.

```
    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/uuuu")
                                .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
    try {
        LocalDate.parse(string, format);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Not a valid date: " + string);
    }
```

While `SimpleDateFormat` has two degrees of strictness, lenient and non-lenient, `DateTimeFormatter` has three, strict, smart and lenient. For validation I recommend strict. Smart is the default, so we need to set it explicitly.

There are many more details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39649815/5772882).

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to use regex. For your date format it should be something like:

```
(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d
```

You can also find more patterns and validate them here: http://html5pattern.com/Dates

Comment: this doesn't work... Feb 29 2016 is actually a valid date!

Comment: Of course it works but only for Gab's date format: dd/MM/yyyy. I thought he's only interested in this format and "Feb 29 2016" is completely different