# Regular expression for XXXXRCYYYYMMDDnnnnnnnn

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to make a regex which will work for the `XXXXRCYYYYMMDDnnnnnnnn` string.

I tried

```
^[A-Z]{6}(?<!\\d)(?:(?:20\\d{2})(?:(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02])31)|(?:(?:0[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(?:29|30)))|(?:(?:20(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))0229)|(?:20\\d{2})(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(?:0?[1-9]|1\\d|2[0-8]))(?!\\d){8}([\\d]{8}$
```

**XXXXRC** are 6 characters and **YYYYMMDD** is date and n's are any numbers.

This looks for **first 6 character** and then for **YYYYMMDD** and then look for **8 numbers**.

It's not working.

Comment: You should specify what you mean with your format string. What are the X, R, C, Y, M, D and n about?

Comment: @Justastudent I edited the question.

Comment: So, `XXXXRC` are all letters? Or just `[A-Z]`? And `n` are digits, `\d`? What's wrong with just having `\p{L}{6}\d{14}`? That would even support Unicode characters.

Comment: I also need to validate date it should not be any invalida date like 1990/32/13 and year should be greater than 2015

Comment: That should have been in your question. Also, I'd like to **strongly** advise you not to do that validation in the regular expression. Instead, take the match and validate it separately. [Like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39649815/962603), for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1:

Use capturing groups to break up the values, then check the values inside the capturing groups if they match a valid date:

```
^([\w]{4})([\w]{2})([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{8})$
```

This will match something like: `ABCDZY1999123101234567` into the following groups:

```
(ABCD)(ZY)(1999)(12)(31)(01234567)
^     ^   ^     ^   ^   ^
|     |   |     |   |   |
|     |   |     |   |   group 5
|     |   |     |   group 4
|     |   |     group 3
|     |   group 2
|     group 1 
group 0
```

In this case, groups 2, 3, and 4 would compose the date components. You can experiment and validate this regular expression through one of the many online RegEx testers, like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/).

## Option 2:

Take the above approach, but get more creative with the number capture groups to include only the date ranges desired. See [Matching Numeric Ranges with a Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html):

examples from the above site:

- 000..255: `^([01][0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$`
- 0 or 000..255: `^([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$`
- 0 or 000..127: `^(0?[0-9]?[0-9]|1[01][0-9]|12[0-7])$`
- 0..999: `^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])$`

However, this approach is *very* difficult to maintain and should only be used if you cannot use option 1 alone.