# Date year value showing valid when invalid

Tags: java, validation, date

I am working on a date app where user will enter date and i am validating that date. Date format is `dd/MM/yyyy`. This is my code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
 //Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  String dat = "02/1/2018";
  try {
             SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                df.setLenient(false);
                df.parse(dat);
                System.out.print("valid");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                System.out.print("invalid");
            }

   }
 }
```

This is working perfect and validating my date but when i enter my date like `22/02/2-19` that also come as valid. But it should be invalid because my year is `2-19`.

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2):

## java.time

You are using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

For a date-only value, use a date-only class: `LocalDate`.

Define your formatting pattern with the `DateTimeFormatter` class. Search Stack Overflow for many more discussions and examples, as this has been covered many many times.

When parsing, trap for [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html) to determine if invalid.

```
String input = "22/02/2-19";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" );
LocalDate ld = null;
try {
    ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f );
    System.out.println( "VALID: " + ld.toString() );
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    System.out.println( "INVALID: " + input );
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> INVALID: 22/02/2-19
>
> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '22/02/2-19' could not be parsed at index 6…

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for `SimpleDateFormat`:

> For parsing, if the number of pattern letters is more than 2, the year is interpreted literally, regardless of the number of digits. So using the pattern "MM/dd/yyyy", "01/11/12" parses to Jan 11, 12 A.D.

This is why the input `22/02/2-19` does not throw a parsing exception. It takes the 2 as the year and ignores the rest.

Comment: So can you please suggest any method to show this invalid?

Comment: You should be able to find that answer by doing your own research. For example I was able to find [a question about this topic with many answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/226910/3284624).

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

[Basil Bourque’s excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51802428/5772882) is already giving the best solution to your problem. I am not repeating that. If using that answer you want to accept 1-digit month as in your first example, `02/1/2018`, you should give only one `M` in the format pattern string. Then both `1` and `01` will be accepted. Similarly one `d` will accept both `2` and `02` for day of month.

### What went wrong in your code

`SimpleDateFormat` reads as much as possible from your string to match the format pattern, but is happy not to read all of it. With your second example, `22/02/2-19`, it parses `22/02/2` into a `Date` of Mon Jan 02 00:00:00 CET 2 (exact result depending on your time zone), which is more than 2016 years ago. Since this is a valid date, it doesn’t throw any exception. It then ignores the last three characters of the string.