# validate a date format in (mm/yyyy) type in java

Tags: java, string, validation, date

how to validate date format `MM/YYYY` as String 
example-

09/20  false

13/5651 false

3/2104 true

03/2010 true

Comment: i tried with sampleDateFormat but it gives 09/20 as true but i need date as full part in 4 numbers

Comment: Right, don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, it’s hard to get right, and the class is long outdated. Use `YearMonth` and `DateTimeFormatter` from java,time, the modern Java date and time API. Also I don’t think you can force `SimpleDateFormat` to reject a 2 or 3 digit year.

Comment: Related: [How to sanity check a date in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226910/how-to-sanity-check-a-date-in-java). Your search engine will be happy to show you more related and inspirational questions and answers.

Comment: You can use a **Regular Expression** (RegEx) along with the **String#matches()** method to validate your **specific** date format, for example: `boolean dateIsValid = dateString.matches("^(0?[1-9]|1[012])\\/[0-9]{4}$");`. I'm not placing this as an answer since you have so many great ones already but if you want an explanation of this RegEx then copy/paste the expression **^(0?[1-9]|1[012])\/[0-9]{4}$** into [RegEx101.com](https://regex101.com/) and read the explanation there.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "M/uuuu" ) ;
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse( "3/2018" , f ) ;
```

Trap for `DateTimeParseException` to detect invalid input.

---

Tip: Use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for exchanging date-time values as text. For year-month: YYYY-MM

The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default.

```
YearMonth.parse( "2018-03" )
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a customized method because you place special constraints to the validity of the date.  
The following passed all your 4 examples:

```
public static boolean validDate(String date) {
    date = date.trim();
    if (date.length() < 6)
        return false;

    String[] parts = date.split("/");
    if (parts.length != 2)
        return false;

    int month = 0;
    try {
        month = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    if (month < 1 || month > 12)
        return false;

    int year = 0;
    try {
        year = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    if (year < 1000)
        return false;

    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "09/20";
    String s2 = "13/5651";
    String s3 = "3/2104";
    String s4 = "03/2010";

    System.out.println(s1 + " " + validDate(s1));
    System.out.println(s2 + " " + validDate(s2));
    System.out.println(s3 + " " + validDate(s3));
    System.out.println(s4 + " " + validDate(s4));
}
```

will print:

```
09/20 false
13/5651 false
3/2104 true
03/2010 true
```

I'm not sure about this part:

```
if (year < 1000)
    return false;
```

you can change it if you like.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I disagree, though. There’s nothing special about the asker’s constraints and therefore no need for a custom solution.The standard library methods used in [Basil Bourque’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52806050/5772882) handle the validation just fine. If needed you may combine with a range check using `ym.isBefore(YM_MIN)` and similar for a maximum `YearMonth`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isThisDateValid(String dateToValidate, String dateFromat){

    if(dateToValidate == null){
        return false;
    }

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFromat);
    sdf.setLenient(false);

    try {

        //if not valid, it will throw ParseException
        Date date = sdf.parse(dateToValidate);
        System.out.println(date);

    } catch (ParseException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Referensi https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-check-if-date-is-valid-in-java/

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.