# Date format matching in Groovy

Tags: java, regex, date, datetime, groovy

Hi I have a string that looks like this - `Wednesday 16 January 2019`.
I want to check in groovy if this date matches with the format `EEEE DD MMMM YYYY`. 
Is there a way to do this?

Are there any inbuilt functions that I can use or regex is my only option?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try parse it with pattern `EEEE dd MMMM yyyy`, if exception is thrown, then it is not in this pattern, in java it looks like:

```
public boolean isInDesiredFormat(String input) {
    try {
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDate.parse(input, format);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
        ignore.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39649815/5772882) you will probably want to apply `ResolverStyle.STRICT ` for stricter validation.