# Check invalid date by LocalDate

Tags: java-8

Java 1.8

Date format "dd.MM.yyyy"

Correct example is : 30.03.2020".

Snippet:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.ResolverStyle;\

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
                        .ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy")
                        .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.LENIENT);
                return LocalDate.parse(dateAsString, formatter);
```

But when I input INCORRECT date:

**35.02.2020**

But my code not throw error. And return date **2020-03-05**

Why?

Comment: Is this the answer you're looking for? [Answer for 'How to sanity check a date in Java'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226910/how-to-sanity-check-a-date-in-java/39649815#39649815). Or are you asking ___why___ there are these modes? Or Something else?

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace [`ResolverStyle.LENIENT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#LENIENT) mode with [`STRICT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#STRICT). Check [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html) for more details

Comment: I get error when input CORRECT date (30.03.2020), error: 
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '30.03.2020' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {MonthOfYear=3, YearOfEra=2020, DayOfMonth=30},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed

Comment: Interesting, it's turned out that you need to specify year as "uuuu" when you use SMART mode, because yyyy is year-of-era. Or you may set SMART mode which is used by default.

Comment: After change to "dd.MM.uuuu" with ResolverStyle.STRICT  the error is gone

Comment: Yeah, strict mode it too strict, hah. I'd suggest you use SMART which is a bit more intuitive.