# Java Instant.parse cannot validate date

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-time, java.time.instant

I have an instant field and trying to validate the values in this field using the following approach:

`Instant.parse("2021-09-29 09:35:07.531")`

However, it throws the error:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-09-29
> 09:35:07.531' could not be parsed at index 10.

So, how can I test if the given `Instant` date in String format is a valid `Instant` date?

I am implementing an Import feature and I need to check the date cells. So, the date is normally kept in Instant format in db and for this reason I need to check if the cell date value is a valid Instant date. So, if there is a more proper way, of course I can follow that approach.

I do not use the value, I just need to check if the date is a valid date.

Comment: Did you try with the right format Instant.parse("2021-09-29T09:35:07.531Z")?

Comment: I thought it, but the data in my database is in this format like `2021-09-29 11:04:12.683`

Comment: So, maybe I need to set this format while parsing. Any idea?

Comment: The exception points to index 10, that's the whitespace in your example `String`. It expects a `T` there. An `Instant` can only be derived from this `String` if you add a `ZoneId` or a `ZoneOffset` at least.

Comment: **Caution:** If you force that string into an Instant, you will be implicitly forcing a timezone which isn’t part of the value, which will probably result in incorrect data.  Read it as a LocalDateTime instead:  `resultSet.getObject(1, LocalDateTime.class)`

Comment: *but the data in my database is in this format like …* No, you’re wrong there.  Your database *displays* that format. Internally it most likely uses some binary format.

Comment: Rather than `datetime` or `timestamp` (without time zone) use the `timestamp with time zone` or `timstamptz` data type of your database (assuming it’s got such, but it’s standard, so it should have). Then you can retrieve either an `Instant` or an `OffsetDateTime`. The latter can be trivially converted to `Instant`.

Comment: *I have an instant field* Where?! In your UI? Your database? Your Java program? Your spreadsheet? …

Comment: I do not use the value, I just need to check if the date is a valid date.

Comment: Robert, thanks for providing additional information since yesterday. It’s great that you do and helps a lot. It’s always best to *edit the question and add information there* so we have everything in one place. When you do it in reaction to comments additionally @-tag the person requesting the information in a comment. This will draw that person’s attention (usually).

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks a lot for this wonderful and useful information. I will keep all of them in consideration. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Date-Time string does not have timezone information and therefore you can not parse it into an `Instant` without introducing a timezone. I recommend you parse it into `LocalDateTime` and use the same for DB work if it is supposed to be used independent of timezones.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2021-09-29 09:35:07.531", dtfInput);
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-09-29T09:35:07.531
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/9SJFB8)

#### How to use `LocalDateTime` in JDBC?

Given below is a sample code to insert a `LocalDateTime` into `columnfoo` (which is of `TIMESTAMP` type):

```
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mytable (columnfoo) VALUES (?)");
st.setObject(1, ldt);
st.executeUpdate();
st.close();
```

Given below is a sample code to retrieve a `LocalDateTime` from `columnfoo`:

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE <some condition>");
while (rs.next()) {
    // Assuming the column index of columnfoo is 1
    LocalDateTime ldt = rs.getObject(1, LocalDateTime.class));
    System.out.println(ldt);
}
rs.close();
st.close();
```

#### In case you want to parse the given Date-Time string into `Instant`:

As described above, you need to introduce a timezone in order to parse it into an `Instant`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Change the ZoneId to the applicable one e.g. ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC")
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH)
                                        .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

        Instant instant = Instant.from(dtfInput.parse("2021-09-29 09:35:07.531"));
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output in my timezone, Europe/London:**

```
2021-09-29T08:35:07.531Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/ayM76n)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

A reference to the time zone is mandatory if you are trying to use the `Instant` class. So, let's try this:

```
LocalDateTime.from(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss.SSS").parse("2021-09-29 09:35:07.351")).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but is it possible without using simpledateformat, etc?

Comment: In my single line code there isn't any `SimpleDateFormat` ref, I'm using only java.time package

Comment: I meant `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: And also it is **not working** :(

Comment: What do you mean with "is not working"?

Comment: `LocalDateTime.from(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss.SSS").parse("2021-09-29 09:35:07.531")).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();` throws "*Cannot find local variable 'LocalDateTime'*" error

Comment: Try with `import java.time.LocalDateTime;`

Comment: I tried, but does not make any sense.

Comment: This should work perfectly fine if you import the class(es) you need, @Robert. However, this answer would be even better if the author had mentioned the core problem: `Instant.parse(String s)` only parses ISO date `String`s and an `Instant` can only be derived from a *full* datetime `String` that includes either an offset or a zone.

Comment: I've just added this detail in my answer. But your suggestion is more detailed yet

Comment: @Renato just add that explanation, maybe choose your own words.

Comment: @deHaar Ok, but what about the solution? How can validate an Instant date in String format?

Comment: You could check for a `DateTimeParseException` but you cannot use a wrong pattern for that and just leave zone and offset because it would always fail. After a successful parsing, you can check for wrong values if you create a `String` from the `Instant` using the same `DateTimeFormatter` and `ZoneId` or `ZoneOffset` and find out if the `String`s are equal. Just suggestions...

Comment: Instead of trying to explain by words, why do not you post an example code to show the correct usage that I need?

Comment: @Robert, why don't you try to write some lines of code that reflect the words you read?

Answer (score 1):

> So, how can I test if the given `Instant` date in String format is a
> valid `Instant` date?

It is not.

An instant is a (unique) point in time. Your string holds a date and time of day. Without knowing the time zone this may denote some point within a range of 24 or 27 hours — so pretty far from being one point in time.

Edit: I understand that you are importing the string from somewhere, that you cannot decide the format or content of the string, and you need to validate it. You can validate it as a date and time. You basically cannot convert it to an `Instant`, or at least you only can under assumptions the validity of which I can’t know. For validation I suggest this formatter:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter PARSER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
        .appendLiteral(' ')
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
        .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT);
```

The formatter reuses built-in formatters and accepts a variable number of decimals in the seconds, which I think will make sense in many contexts. You know better whether it does in yours.

Validate like this:

```
    String importedDateTimeString = "2021-09-29 09:35:07.531";
    try {
        LocalDateTime.parse(importedDateTimeString, PARSER);
        System.out.format("Valid date and time: %s%n", importedDateTimeString);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
        System.out.format("Not a valid date and time: %s. Validation error: %s%n",
                importedDateTimeString, dtpe);
    }
```

Output:

> Valid date and time: 2021-09-29 09:35:07.531

Original recommendation: So instead use a format that includes offset from UTC. In particular the ISO 8601 format for an instant in UTC is a recommended option for several purposes, like `2021-09-29T01:35:07.531Z`.

Link: [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Thanks for useful explanations. You right, but I cannot change the date format and for this reason I have to check this format (`2021-09-29 09:35:07.531`) as a string. Is that impossible by some conversion as well?

Comment: Sorry, your question still isn’t clear to me. If you convert the string to something else, is it then the string you are checking? And what are the reason for and the purpose of the validation? Does this answer your question? [How to sanity check a date in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226910/how-to-sanity-check-a-date-in-java)

Comment: I am implementing an Import feature and I need to check the date cells. So, the date is normally kept in Instant format in db and for this reason I need to check if the cell date value is a valid Instant date. So, if there is a more proper way, of course I can follow that approach but I have no prior experience :(

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I have edited the answer to fit with what I understood from your comment.